# How to get access to template in asyncData?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I want to get access to this.$el in asyncData.
I use a database to store translations.
I want to get a list of translations that are used on the current page.
Then I will send a request to the server to receive them.
After that, I will merge it.

```js
i18.mergeLocaleMessage( locale, message )
```

How to do it ?

Comment: What did you tried so far ? What do you mean by `$el`?

Comment: @kissu I want to get access to template, before it is mounted. it is necessary for seo.

Comment: Like a specific `div` ? Usually, you do have the SEO in the `head()`. Other info, can be get through `$refs` or the `script` tag. Do you have an example template of what you do want to get ?

Comment: No. I use nuxt-i18n for translate. In template {{ $t('Hello') ]}, when there is access to $ el, then translations are already loaded, and I want to load them for the current page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `i18n` with something like this, no need to access the template for this use case

```js
asyncData ({ app }) {
  console.log(app.i18n.t('Hello'))
}
```

---

Looking at the [lifecycle of Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle), `asyncData` will happen before any template is generated at all, so it is impossible with `asyncData`.
And even if it was possible with some hacky trick, it would be a bit strange to have to look inside of your template to then have some logic for i18n fetching.

Why not getting a `computed` nested object and loop on this through your template, after you have fetched all of your required translations ?

Also, you're using `asyncData` + an API call each time ? So, for every page: you will stop the user, let him wait for the API call and then proceed ?

Latest point, if you are on your page and you hit `F5`, then `asyncData` hook will not be triggered. Just to let you know about this caveat.

#### Alternative solutions:

- using the `fetch()` hook and display a loader until you have fetched all your translations, still better to not rely on the content of the template. This will work even on `F5` and can produce a more smooth experience (by not blocking the navigation).
- getting your `i18n` whole translations globally, at some point when your user's connection is idle. Rather than on per-page. Especially because you will need to handle the logic of not fetching some translations that you already have (if the user visits a page twice).

Comment: How do I know what translations are needed for a page?

Comment: Edited my answer. Also, do you use nuxt as universal or SPA only ?